# как из shell-а получить http-заголовки?

Tags: http, shell, faq

как из shell-а получить *http*-заголовки, возвращаемые моим (и не только) *http*-сервером в ответ на *http*-запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в операционной системе *gnu/linux* это можно сделать, например, с помощью программ `curl` или `wget` — самых, наверно, популярных *http*-клиентов (есть и множество менее популярных).

### curl

```
$ curl -I 'http://yandex.ru'
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved temporarily
Location: http://www.yandex.ru/
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

$
```

### wget

```
$ wget -qS --spider --max-redirect=0 'http://yandex.ru'
  HTTP/1.1 302 Moved temporarily
  Location: http://www.yandex.ru/
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
$
```

Comment: Такой хитрый способ срубить лишних плюсов?)

Comment: @PloadyFree, загляните, пожалуйста, в [справку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Просто сначала вылезла мысль о [самоучке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner). Извиняюсь)