# HostCMS. Internal server error. Редиректы и htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cms

Открывая страницу вида http://site.com/contacts/ или http://site.com/concerts/
получаю ошибку в error_log

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. 
>   Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. 
>   Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

В файле .htaccess прописано следующее

```
php_value memory_limit "32M"

AddHandler custom-php .php .pcgi
Action custom-php /cgi-bin/php.cgi

<IfModule mod_php4.c>
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
php_flag register_globals off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
php_flag register_globals off
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymlinks
#DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

При этом сама ошибка кроется где-то в этих двух строках

```html
    AddHandler custom-php .php .pcgi
    Action custom-php /cgi-bin/php.cgi
```

Когда отключаю их, предлагает загрузить Zend Optimizer.

В cgi-bin лежат следующие файлы:

```html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Aug 19  2009 ZendOptimizer.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Nov 10  2014 php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 Sep 11  2014 php4.cgi
```

Сам с этим сталкиваюсь впервые и не могу понять как это работает, чтобы исправить.
Как исправить данную проблему?

UPD: http заголовки

```html
wget -qS --spider --max-redirect=0 tverd.com/concerts/
  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
  Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2015 10:55:23 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
  Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2015 10:55:24 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Content-Length: 670
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Что попадает в access_log при запросе страницы:

```html
[02/Aug/2015:04:00:25 -0700] "GET /concerts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 619 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36" 
[02/Aug/2015:04:00:25 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1423 "http://tverd.com/concerts/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36"
```

UPD.2: Возможно на сервере обновлялась версия PHP, потому как сайт какое-то время работал исправно и никто его не трогал (на севрере установлен репозиторий). Сейчас php 5.4

Comment: У вас зацикливание реврайта вообще-то.

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу [возвращаемые http-сервером заголовки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439178/178576).

Comment: и ошибки из лога http-сервера приложите, пожалуйста.

Comment: про зацикливание рерайта я догадался) а вот определить где оно циклится не могу.

Comment: заголовки приложил. выше в вопросе сделал UPD.

Comment: Александр, эррор лог приложен выше. аксесс лог тоже приаттачил в апдейте